# At / in those moments - would be + verb form

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

> The only thing I'd love to do at / in those moments (stressful ones) would be to hang out / hang out / hanging out with my friends.

I have two questions about this sentence:

- Which is the correct preposition at / in those moments? Why?
- What verb form should follow "would be" in my sentence: infinitive / base form / gerund?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence should be:

*The only thing I'd love to do in those moments (stressful ones) would be to hang out with my friends.*